# max and min function in google app engine using jdo

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

been trying to retrieve records with max values and min values in google appengine using JDO,
i understand  that its not supported..does anybody have an idea to carry out this query against entities in a datastore...below is my code

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

  Query q=pm.newQuery(userentity.class);

  q.setFilter("Cusunique == CusUniqueId");              

  q.declareParameters("String CusUniqueId");
  //JDO does not allow this below line of code
  q.setResult("max(this.fieldname)");
```

Answer (score 0):

**JDO** does **not** place any restriction on you doing that. GAE v1 plugin may do, but GAE v2 plugin certainly does not. Obviously any restrictions of the datastore are something else.

PS. Way more efficient to simply write

```
q = pm.newQuery("SELECT max(this.fieldname) FROM mydomain.userentity WHERE Cusunique == :id");
```

Comment: I think it's better to write : `Query q=pm.newQuery(UserEntity.class); ` than embed it in a string. What if you change the package name of the class ?